# Perl hash of hash of lists from Net::LDAP to a 'filtered' list

Tags: perl, ldap

The [`Net::LDAP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aLDAP) module for Perl provides an Net::LDAP::Search  object. Its `as_struct` method returns the structure below.

Multiple entries as

```
$entry{dn=...} = 
ref {cn} = ref {name}
ref {l} = ref {city}
ref{mail} = ref {xxxxxx}
```

An example:

```
uid=pieterb,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org {key of first hash = dn in ldap}
uid=pieterb {key=uid}
cn=Pieter B. {key=cn}
uidNumber=1000 {key=uidNumber}
gidNumber=4000 {key=gidNumber}

uid=markc,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org {key of first hash = dn in ldap }
uid=markc {key=uid}
cn=Mark Cole {key=cn}
uidNumber=1001 {key=uidNumber}
gidNumber=4000 {key=gidNumber}
```

However, the interface uses [`UI::Dialog`](https://metacpan.org/module/UI%3a%3aDialog) which expects a list in the format below (radiolist/checklist), with data coming from the attribute values in the LDAP server

```
list => [ 
'Pieter B.', ['uid=pieterb,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org',0],
'Mark Cole', ['uid=markc,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org',0],
'cn_value(openldap)',['dn_value',0],
'givenname_value(activedirectory)',['dn_value',0]
]
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I know what `Net::LDAP` does but cannot relate what you describe to the result of `Net::LDAP::as_struct`. What do the `ref {xx}` items mean? What do the `attribute(ex 'xx') value` items mean? Does `ex` mean *example*? Which method of `UI::Dialog` are you using (`checklist` perhaps)? The examples of list structures that you want contain strings that don't appear anywhere in your LDAP data so I can't tell how you want to transform one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to guess what you want, but I think it is a list of the LDAP attribute names versus their values.

You should look at [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) to examine and present the data structures you are dealing with.

You don't mention what to do if the data you get from the search contains multiple *Distinguished Names*, or multiple values for an attribute, but this code simply takes the first DN and the first value in lists of attribute values to generate a list of lists.

I have little doubt that this isn't exactly what you need, and if you specify your requirement better we will be able to help further.

```
my $data = $msg->as_struct;
my $entry = (values %$data)[0];

my @attributes = map {
  $_, [$entry->{$_}[0], 0]
} keys %$entry;

$dialog->checklist(list => \@attributes);
```

Comment: I''ll try using your tips, seems I can't edit my original post because of code formatting issues...